# How to get Unit component? Can i use addAsync for get solution?

Tags: tdd

I want to built a program which is get problems and I found that my first batches of  tests involving custom components would tend to follow code:

```
 import mx.core.Application;     
 import mx.events.FlexEvent;
 import flexunit.framework.TestCase;
public class CustomComponentTest extends TestCase { 
private var component:CustomComponent;
public function testSomeAspect() : void {
component = new CustomComponent();
component.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, 
addAsync(verifySomeAspect, 5000));
component.height = 0;
component.width = 0;
Application.application.addChild(component);
}

 public function verifySomeAspect(event:FlexEvent) : void {}

override public function tearDown() : void {
 try {
if (component) {
Application.application.removeChild(component);
component = null;
}
} catch (e:Error) {
 }
 }
```

First, you need to make sure the component has been fully initialized before you can reliably verify anything about it, and in Flex this happens asynchronously after it has been added to the display list. So you need to setup a callback (using FlexUnit's addAsync function) to be notified when that's happened.
Lately i've been just manually calling the methods that the runtime would call for you in the necessary places, so now my tests tend to look more like this:

```
import flexunit.framework.TestCase;
public class CustomComponentTest extends TestCase {
public function testSomeAspect() : void {
var component:CustomComponent = new CustomComponent();
 component.initialize();
 component.validateProperties();
 }
```

This is much easier to follow, but it kinda feels like I'm cheating a little either way. The first case is slamming it into the current Application (which would be the unit test runner shell app), and the latter isn't a "real" environment.I was wondering how other people would handle this sort of situation?

Comment: Pls add more specific language tags like Java!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can agree that the second version is shorter, but I'm not sure that I think it's easier to follow. The test does a lot of things that you wouldn't normally do, whereas the first example is more true to how you would use the component outside the test environment.

Also, in the second form you have to make sure that you do exactly what the framework would do, miss one step and your test isn't relevant, and each test must repeat this code. Seems to me it's better to test it in a situation that is as close to the real thing as possible.

You could have a look at dpUint's sequences, they made component testing a little more declarative:

```
 public function testLogin():void {
 var passThroughData:Object = new Object();
 passThroughData.username = "myuser1";
  passThroughData.password = "somepsswd";
  var sequence:SequenceRunner = new SequenceRunner(this);
    sequence.addStep(new SequenceSetter(form.usernameTI, 

   {text:passThroughData.username}));
    sequence.addStep(new SequenceWaiter(form.usernameTI,     

    FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT, 100));
  sequence.addStep(new SequenceSetter(form.passwordTI, 

   {text:passThroughData.password}));
    sequence.addStep(new SequenceWaiter(form.passwordTI, FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT, 100));
    sequence.addStep(new SequenceEventDispatcher(form.loginBtn,

    new MouseEvent("click", true, false)));
      sequence.addStep(new SequenceWaiter(form, "loginRequested", 100));
         sequence.addAssertHandler(handleLoginEvent, passThroughData);
      sequence.run();}
```